# Looping on object from endpoint query

Tags: php, arrays, api, endpoint

I have a function returning the following from an API search endpoint:

```
{#1090 ▼
+"took": 3
+"timed_out": false
+"_shards": {#1141 ▶}
+"hits": {#1309 ▼
  +"total": 231
  +"max_score": null
  +"hits": array:10 [▼
    0 => {#1191 ▼
      +"_index": "products"
      +"_type": "product"
      +"_id": "1634"
      +"_score": 5.7772136
      +"_source": {#1214 ▼
        +"category_wrapper_detail": "General 1234:0 - Dark Green 123:25"
        +"wrappers": {#1344 ▼
          +"1": {#1298 ▼
            +"wrapper_code": "123"
            +"id": 525
            +"detail_name": "Dark Green"
            +"detail_code": "25"
          }
        }
        +"template": {#1216 ▼
          +"category": {#1138 ▼
            +"category_code": "1234"
            +"category_name": "General"
            +"category_subcat": 0
            +"id": 135
          }
        }
      }
      +"fields": {#1116 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#1114 ▶}
    2 => {#1083 ▶}
    3 => {#1021 ▶}
    4 => {#950 ▶}
    5 => {#929 ▶}
    6 => {#764 ▶}
    7 => {#770 ▶}
    8 => {#703 ▶}
    9 => {#1535 ▶}
  ]
}
```

}

The result is correct, but my problem is I don't know how I should loop over this properly. I get the above object by doing  `dd($searchResults)`.

You can see there are 10 array elements for 'hits', so I want to say "For each 'hits' result, set 'fieldname' = category_wrapper_detail and then set each other value to it's own variable"

I'm trying this:

```
foreach($searchResults as $result['hits'] => $result){
  foreach($result['source'] as $source){
      //This is the full concatenated result for a label
      $fullResult = ['category_wrapper_detail'];

      //The following are the individual results that I'll save on the backend eventually
      $categoryName = ['category_name'];
      $categoryCode = ['category_code'];
      $categorySubcat = ['category_subcat'];
      $detailName = ['detailName'];
      $wrapperCode = ['wrapper_code'];
      $detailCode = ['detail_code'];
  }
}
```

But it's not working and I think it has to do with the nested loop.

How can I only return my needed values for each result here?

Comment: `foreach($searchResults['hits'] as $hit => $result)` would be better start.

Comment: are you getting data from elasticsearch ?

Comment: @smart-googler yes it's an elasticsearch integration in our API

Comment: @Whisou138 can you edit your code snippet and post the array `print '<pre>';print_r($searchResult['hits']['hits']); print '</pre>';` instead of api response?

Comment: I put this in but I get 'cannot use stdClass as array?

Comment: then try like this                                                                                                        `$searchResult = json_decode($searchResult,1); print '<pre>';print_r($searchResult['hits']['hits']); print '</pre>';`

Comment: The page is loading now but it's just printing null

Comment: my controller is just creating a new instance of the hit to the endpoint and storing in a variable, not an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178875/discussion-between-smart-googler-and-whisou138).

Comment: @smart-googler did I lose you in the chat a while ago?